# Right angled car cigarette lighter adapter

Tags: adapter

My car's cigarette lighter is situated so that any devices I put into it protrude and brush my hand when I change gear, which is very annoying (and potentially dangerous).

I am looking for something, possibly right angled not protruding too much, ideally something that just fits into the lighter and does not stick out, extruding only a wire connected to another female lighter adapter.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you have now? What does it need at the other end, USB C, Lightning, etc?

Comment: I will try to make a photos. I want another (female) cigarette lighter socket at the other end; basically, just an extension cord, which does not protrude

Comment: You could always make your own too with a male and a female one and some wire. This would also allow you to mount the female side whereever you want instead of having a rigid extension

Answer (score 2):

A few years late, but may help others

[image]

[Edco Angled Cigarette Lighter Hella Adapter Socket | 12v / 24v](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Angled-Cigarette-Lighter-Adapter-Socket/dp/B00BJ382MA)